# Control-drag in Xcode gives outlets, but no action for UIButton. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

In my app I'm building, I've got a Navigation Controller with a View Controller connected as a subview (is that the right word?). I added a UIButton and tried to Control-drag it into my view controller class file, but it's only giving me Outlet and Outlet collection as my options, not Action.

[Screenshot of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZgY.png)

It's a pretty simple app, and I've tried removing my Pods as a fix, but so far no luck.

I've also tried manually writing the function and trying to connect it back to the button, but to no avail. Dragging back to the button in the workspace doesn't work, and the function isn't firing when I test the app. Here's the code I tried:

```
@IBAction func tapSaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {}
```

It's probably something simple, so what am I missing here?

EDIT: Also, here's how I'm set up. I have a Navigation Controller with a UINavigationItem that shows a sub ViewController. The button in question is in the sub ViewController and I setup a new swift file to handle that ViewController's class. I'm trying to connect that button into that class file, and that's where it's not working.

[Screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkcrx.png)

Here's my ViewController class's code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import KeychainSwift


class SettingsViewController : UIViewController {

    let keychain = KeychainSwift()

    @IBOutlet weak var APIKeyField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var WebSocketIPField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SettingsSaveButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        /* My other code, not related */
    }

    @IBAction func tapSaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // My button actions here.

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the "type" of your button `SaveButton`? Is that a custom class or an error?

Comment: Can you show also what "Object" is there ? and paste your SaveButton class code

Comment: @MatthewSeaman That's a custom class. I named my button SaveButton, so it automatically selected that when I dragged over. Changing it to UIButton doesn't affect anything unfortunately.

Comment: @AhmadF No luck unfortunately.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I added a bit more information into my description. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Have you set the IB class for your view controller to SettingsViewController?

Comment: @dfd I did, but I'm thinking I might recreate the whole thing to make sure it's connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it was something dumb. I removed the class from the button, and viola, it let me create an action in my Swift file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you tried to connect to other viewcontroller
please check again it is correct viewcontroller and connected on storyboard exactly

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the uibutton within storyboard, you should see a list of action options under "Sent Events" the most common one to use is "Touch Up Inside".

Drag from the one you want (circle to the side) onto your view controller and everything should work fine.

EDIT: For clarity, you can even drag from "Touch Up Inside" to the func you've already created so long as it's labeled

```
@IBAction ...
```

which your code already has done.

[image: Here's an example of what I mean]

[image: After you control drag it looks like this]

[image: Select the view controller, and assign the class]

Comment: Interestingly I don't have any of those events available on this button. Am I missing something in my ViewController? All I have is Triggered Segues, Referencing Outlets, and Referencing Outlet Collections. 

The button in my initial ViewController in my UINavigationController has all those actions available however

Comment: @CharlesForster I just made a mockup of your program. It's working perfectly. Are you sure that your "class" of your view controllers are associated with your swift files? See the third image I'm uploading now.

Comment: I would also check the class of your button, using the same logic as the view controller, to make sure it's properly subclassing UIButton and that's it's properly selected.

Comment: Yup, that helped me out. Basically if you have a specific class on your button, it doesn't give you the "Action" option. As soon as I cleared that field in the options, voila, I have actions available again.

Answer (score 0):

It's also happen with me, when i added localization in my project, from that time which storyboard was added in localization, that storyboard buttons are not showing any action option, only showing outlet options.